# Отмена функции при неактивном input поле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Функция собирает из инпутов данные и выводит их в title и h1. Нужно чтобы при неактивных чекбоксах значение title и h1 возвращались в первоначальный вид, без перезагрузки. Или возможно отсечь вывод name и description сайта в h1, и вывести только значения которые были собраны в title?

```
(function($) {

function updateTitle() {
    $.get(location.href, function (html) {
        var title = $(html).filter('title').text();
        document.title = title;
        $('h1').text(title);
    });
}

$('.my_filter_widget').on("change", "input, select", function () {
    setTimeout(updateTitle, 2); 
});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `onblur`. Документация - [вот](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur)

```js
var inp = document.getElementById("inp");

inp.onblur = function() {
  heading.innerHTML = "Текст по умолчанию";
}

inp.oninput = function() {
  heading.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<h1 id = "heading">Текст по умолчанию</h1>

<input type = "text" id = "inp" value = "Текст по умолчанию">
```

**P.S.:** я переделал ваш код полностью.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересный метод.

Comment: @Wooo, незачто!

Comment: @Wooo если вам ответ помог, пожалуйста, поставтье ему плюс, или галочку

Comment: Только вот с чекбоксом не работает.